# Call Wordpress category by name instead of ID

Tags: wordpress

I'm working on a local copy of a WP site, but when we move it live all of the category IDs will change, so I need to find a way to call things by name instead of ID. Right now I have this:

```
$myposts = get_posts('numberposts=3&category=3599');
```

I actually need to show posts from two categories, so instead of the category being 3599, I need it to be Technology and Technology News. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`get_posts` can use all parameters that the `WP_Query` can, so try this:

```
$myposts = get_posts('numberposts=3&category_name=[Technology],[Technology News]');
```

Replace [Technology] and [Technology News] with the **slug name** of the two respective categories (and remove the brackets, of course). Make sure you use the slug name and not the regular name or it won't work.

Also, please *make sure* to test this first. I ran a brief test on a local installation of WordPress 3.5.0, but I don't think I have to emphasize to you that you should make sure it works as expected on your end!

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks. This doesn't seem to quite work - it shows posts from all the categories instead of just those two. I tried doing just one category, and found the same problem.

Comment: I don't understand why it didn't work for you, because the code you put in your answer below is the *exact* code you should have gotten from the recipe I gave you, replacing [Technology] with "technology", and [Technology News] with "technology-news", that is, the category slug names.

Comment: I apologize - I didn't notice that you had switched category to category name - my fault.

Comment: That's quite all right. Reading lines of code can be really tricky sometimes, especially when they're recipe-like, which mine was. Glad you were able to resolve your trouble.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to call the name in an array like so. 
    $myposts = get_posts(
    'name' => 'News',
    );

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_category

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out - I just needed to change 'category' to 'category_name'

```
$myposts = get_posts('numberposts=3&category_name=technology,technology-news');
```

Comment: The site won't let you pick your own answer as correct until it's been posted for 2 days. But really raphaelvalerio deserves the credit - he gave the right answer, I just misread what he wrote and didn't realize until he pointed it out.